# How do I match and reorder lists in rust?

Tags: rust

I have two lists in my code, and I'd like to reorder them so they match. The lists in question always have 12 words, and they are always in random order. Here's an example:

```
let s1: Vec<&str> = "alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliett kilo lima".split_whitespace().collect();
let s2: Vec<&str> = "golf juliett foxtrot india hotel lima delta echo kilo alpha charlie bravo".split_whitespace().collect();
```

Now I have a list I can select strings from, like this:

```
println!("{}", s1[0]); // This will print alpha
println!("{}", s2[0]); // This will print golf
```

I want know if there is a way to reorder the lists so that they match with each other like this:

```
println!("{}", s1[0]); // This will print alpha
println!("{}", s2[0]); // This will print alpha as well
```

And also:

```
println!("{}", s1[1]); // This will print bravo
println!("{}", s2[1]); // This will print bravo as well
```

And so on for all the strings in the lists.

Comment: How does the result differ from `s2 = s1;`?

Comment: How about make s2 a clone of s1: `let s2 = s1.clone()`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each vector contains the same words but in different order, you can call the `sort` method on each vector so that they're both in the same order.

```
let mut s1: Vec<&str> = "alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliett kilo lima".split_whitespace().collect();
let mut s2: Vec<&str> = "golf juliett foxtrot india hotel lima delta echo kilo alpha charlie bravo".split_whitespace().collect();

    s1.sort();
    s2.sort();
    println!("{:?}", s1[0]);
    println!("{:?}", s2[0]);
```